# Why is there an error in ChartJs.Blazor (change in ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT)

Tags: c#, chart.js, blazor

I have installed a NugetPacket: ChartJs.Blazor (v1.1.0). In a _Host.cshtml file have added

```
 <script src="_content/ChartJs.Blazor/moment-with-locales.min.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>

<!-- Reference the included ChartJs javascript file. -->
<script src="_content/ChartJs.Blazor/Chart.min.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>

<!-- This is the glue between the C# code and the ChartJs charts -->
<script src="_content/ChartJs.Blazor/ChartJsBlazorInterop.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>

<!-- Some styling -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="_content/ChartJs.Blazor/ChartJSBlazor.css" />
```

When the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT is set to **Development** it works, but when ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT is changed to **Production** app crashes and returns error:

```html
Microsoft.JSInterop.JSException: Could not find 'ChartJsInterop' in 'window'.
Error: Could not find 'ChartJsInterop' in 'window'.
```

Why is there the error in the Production and not in the Development mode? Any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you didn't add it inside an `<environment>` HTML tag? Example:

```html
<environment exclude="Production">
   <script src="_content/ChartJs.Blazor/ChartJsBlazorInterop.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>
</environment>
```

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/environment-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: The code is only placed inside a <body> tag. Environment is define in launchSettings.json "environmentVariables".

Comment: Can you verify using developer tools in the browser that the file is even being retrieved from the server and present in the compiled HTML?

Comment: If I go under inspect -> Sources there is a "file" _content/CharJs.Blazor and inside that is ChartJSBlazor.css. If I click on the ChartJSBlazor.css there is nothing inside (it is empty no content). What coud be the problem?

Comment: @kartaku It sounds silly but right-click the solution and go to 'Clean Solution'. Then try it again. It seems the files are not being included in the output directory.

Comment: I tried "Clean Solution", "Rebuild Solution" and "Build Solution" but non worked.